# What is the best datatype to store 18 digit numeric value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rdbms

What is the best data type to store 18 digit numeric value in MySQL

- The number is always positive
- This column will be a primary key and partition column
- The number of precision is always `18`
- The number of decimals is always `0`

There are multiple datatypes

```
BIGINT
FLOAT(18,0)
DECIMAL(18,0)
DOUBLE(18,0)
```

What is the industry standard and most efficient datatype in MySQL for storage and retrival of such values.

Comment: By 18 digit numeric value, do you mean the values from the range of the data type `long` (or `BIGINT` in MySQL), which uses 64bit storage? Or do you save the number with the digit `9` written 18 times as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. It can support at least 19 digits of precision. The maximum value is 18446744073709551615.

There's no advantage to using DECIMAL, FLOAT, or DOUBLE in this case, because you say the values have no scale.

But you do need 18 digits of precision, so the [rounding behavior of FLOAT/DOUBLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html) may not do what you need.